# Counter not generating properly

Tags: swift, xcode6, counter

Basically what I want to do is code a counter that adds one every time two objects(Wall & Player) collide. This is my whole code:

```
var PlayerTimer : NSTimer!
@IBOutlet var Wall: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Player: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet  var CountLabel: UILabel!
var CountNumber : Int!

func Add() {

    CountNumber = CountNumber + 1
    CountLabel.text = "\(CountNumber)"
}

func PlayerMoving() {

    Player.center = CGPointMake(Player.center.x, Player.center.y + 1)
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Player.frame, Wall.frame)){
        Add()
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    CountNumber = 0
    PlayerTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: Selector("PlayerMoving"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a override nib.
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

But what happens is that after the player moves and hits the wall, a 1 is added but the view resets. For example when the player hits the wall and a 1 is added, the player goes back to its initial position at the top of the view. What I want to happen is for my Player to just keep falling in the same direction after the the collision. Thanks.

Comment: can you show the code for PlayerMoving?

Comment: That's it                                                                             func PlayerMoving() {

    Player.center = CGPointMake(Player.center.x, Player.center.y + 1)
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Player.frame, Wall.frame)){
        Add()
    }
}